# Inserción de imagenes en un PDF con PHP

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, canvas

buenos dias, veran, estoy tratando de hacer un sistema donde un usuario genere su firma puño y letra y después esta firma se guarde como imagen dentro de los archivos del usuario, por seguridad, después el usuario suba un archivo a una base de datos, o elija un archivo que está en la base de datos y proceda a firmarlo, esto con la firma que genero anteriorimente, o sea, pegar esa imagen de la firma en el PDF, y se guarde el pdf en la base de datos, reemplazando el original, pero ahora como nombreDocFirmado.pdf, no se si me explique, ya tengo toda la parte de la generación de la firma con Canvas y AJAX e igual la parte de subir los archivos a la base de datos, me falta como pegar la firma o bien la imagen en el PDF, la verdad no tengo ni la menor idea, investigue que con fpdf se podía, sin embargo, lo intente y no pude, anexo mi código, aclaro, no se como usar dicha biblioteca, intente lo que entendi

```
<?php  
require_once('fpdf.php'); // Incluímos las librerías anteriormente mencionadas
require_once('fpdi.php'); // Incluímos las librerías anteriormente mencionadas

$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("./htdocs/pdf");
$template = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($template);
$pdf->Image('./htdocs/doc_signs', $x, $y, $width, $height);
$pdf->Output($nuevoNombreDelPDF, "ArchivoFirmado");
?>
```

El archivo pdf está guardado tambien en una carpeta del usuario, y en la base de datos, la firma solo en los documentos del usuario.

Comment: necesitas tener la firma por ejemplo en PNG y cargarla con "http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php" despues deberas convertir tu PDF en imagen y colocar la firma dentro de las imagenes extraidas del PDF, y despues hacer el codigo que publicaste.

Comment: Si es algo tedioso porque deberas calcular las dimenciones de las hojas del PDF, despues colocarlo tipo "marca de agua", en una ubicacion especifica (usando X y Y), despues guardar.